# What is the difference between connection string storage with Azure KeyVault and encryption with ASP.net IIS_Reg?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, iis, azure-keyvault

Recently stored our projects connection strings via Azure Key vault and retrieve them with the Azure key vault config builder for our local builds. This lets us get rid of of our connection string in our source control repo. A fellow dev told me I should look into encrypting with ASP.NET IIS_Reg as it's the "de facto standard" for web.config secret encryption. I can't really find any doc that compares these two techniques. Is it possible/ Would it be redundant to try and use both? Can they be used in tandem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Azure Key Vault** today, then I would continue to do so, as that is a more future-proof approach than encrypting things in web.config. Especially if you later want to migrate to .NET Core, then your can still keep using AKV.

Encrypting things in **web.config** is just a pain to administrate. With AKV you can version your secrets and you can better control who has access to what.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel under pressure to provide some more proof as to why I'm choosing not to pursue this. Is there any documentation I can point to that states this?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, then you could use the IIS identity to connect to your databases and then you don't need to encrypt your connection string because they don' contain any passwords. Besides from that I don't have any good reference to point to. Alternatively, you can keep your secrets outside web.config/IIS-folder , like in an external config file or in registry. If the hacker is inside your machine, then its game over anyway.

Comment: Another thing is that when you encrypt things in web.config (as far as I know), the encrypted data is tied to the machine it runs on. So if you need to rebuild your machine or scale out, then you need to re-encrypt all the stuff in web.config.